# What should be the core size, SWG #, # of turns for 100VA isolation transformer to run 100 watts bulb at .5 amps & 230 volts?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, electromagnetism, current-transformer

I am a certified computer programmer, but not an electrician.  After researching on google, youtube, reading few books and referring to some local technicians, I made a transformer on a toroidal core with 100 turns of 18 SWG wire for both primary and secondary. When I tried testing it, my home fuse burnt out. I guess my calculations were not right.

I want to know the formulae and calculations one should follow in order to make a transformer of a particular type (step-up, step-down or isolation) for a specific load of VA.

My requirement is that I'll connect it directly to my mains of 230 volts AC instead of a variac (to save variac cost.) I want to run a 100 watt incandescent light bulb that consumes 0.4347 amps at 230 volts. I want to know what core size for EI type cores I should choose, what size SWG wire I should choose for primary and secondary, how many turns should I put on primary and secondary so that the transformer consumes 230V and 0.6A at primary and delivers 230V and 0.4A (after losses) at the secondary. Should I also be aware of the type of tape or paper I choose to laminate the core before winding? Do I also need to calculate the inductance, magnetic fields, flux & capacitance (stray)? Is there any other thing I should be aware of in order to build a successful transformer?

The important factor is safety.  How can I safely test the newly built transformer without burning out the house fuse?  Are there safety measures I need to take in order to protect myself from injury?

Comment: What sort of core did you use? Was it steel or ferrite?

Comment: The easiest way to isolate a light bulb is to opto-couple the output :)

Comment: You want an isolation transformer for a _light bulb_?

Comment: Certainly, if you live in the US your best bet is to buy a complete transformer from a surplus house.  For a custom transformer that runs off of the mains, your best bet is to buy a stock transformer from a surplus house, and rewind the secondaries (I don't know about isolation transformers, but regular old power transformers either put the secondaries next to, or on top of, the primary windings -- at least in the few transformers that I've rewound).  This should be the kind of thing that electronics repair technicians use, and so it shouldn't be too terribly expensive to buy.

Comment: Or buy two transformers, i.e. 230 -> 24V, and connect the secondaries together.  Then you'll have one very expensive, heavy, and inefficient isolation transformer -- but you won't have to mess with winding your own.

Comment: You can wire a 100 watt incandescent lamp in series with the input before connecting it to 220 VAC mains, with output open. If the lamp lights up, the primary is saturating, and you will only have a few volts on the output. Another safety measure is to use a GFCI circuit in case you have excess insulation leakage or breakdown. You can get a 200 VA transformer kit for $80, but might be 120V primary: https://toroid.com/product/transformer-kit-200va-401-020/

Comment: @qrk I used ferrite core, but now I want to use steel core.

Comment: @Jasen i want to build a transformer not just to isolate the load, but for some other thing, this isolation transformer is a part of other experiment.

Comment: @TimWescott I don't just want isolation transformer for a bulb, I am learning to build transformers, so I thought I should start with a bulb as load, once I make isolation transformer, I'll move on to bigger projects. So I need help.

Comment: @Yogie Ferrite core for low frequency is a bad choice. Steel core is better suited for low frequencies.

Comment: @Yogie: shamelessly copying someone else's engineering is a valid approach -- and one of the things you get from modifying someone else's transformers is an insight into what they do.  Even if you don't know _why_, it still gives you a lot of _what_.

Comment: If you can find someone who sells bare transformer cores, they should have guidelines on how to use them.  You do want cores that are made _specifically for AC_, and moreover, are made for your local line frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide any information about the transformer core, I'll answer with generalizations. You need to consider many parameters when designing a transformer. In your case I believe you are *saturating the core*, i.e., the flux density is too high for the core material. When core saturates, the winding will look like a very low impedance component - approaching the DC resistance of the wire.

**Flux density:**
$$ \hat B_e = {\hat E \over {\omega N A_e}}$$
Where:
\$ \hat E \$ = peak voltage for sine wave, for square wave multiply the peak voltage by 1.57.
\$ \omega \$ = angular frequency = \$ 2 \pi f \$
\$ A_e \$ = core area [m<sup>2</sup>]
\$ N \$ = number of turns

This formula says that you need to exceed a certain number of turns to keep the flux density under the saturation flux density of the transformer core. The saturation flux density can be found in the data sheet for the transformer core along with the core area.

**Magnetizing inductance:**
To prevent excess current draw, the magnetizing inductance (inductance of the primary of the unloaded transformer) needs to be high enough where it won't consume excessive current. My rule of thumb is to keep the magnetizing inductive reactance at least 5 times higher than the load impedance. You may want the magnetizing inductance to be higher for a transformer designed for AC mains usage.

$$ L = N^2 A_L 10^{-9} \quad \text {in henrys} $$
Where \$ A_L \$ = inductance factor in \$ nH/N^2 \$

The inductance factor can be found in the data sheet for the transformer core.

There are other factors such as proper wire diameter. Proximity effect loss is something to watch out for in magnetic designs. For low power 50Hz transformers, proximity effect can probably be ignored.
Winding geometry controls leakage inductance (coupling factor). For a power transformer, low leakage inductance (coupling factor approaching 1.0) is desirable.

Comment: I'll use EI steel core. I have read that the core area = sqrt of VA, so in my case sqrt of 100 is 10, so the core area should be 3.3 inch x 3.3 inch, but what if I take core sheets of larger core area, lets say 10 inch x 10 inch? Will it just reduce the number of turns per volt, or will also reduce/increase the power, or something else? Please enilghten me!

Comment: I also want to keep the no load primary impedance high, so it draws less power when secondary is open, that's an important requirement, please explain the process to achieve it in layman terms, I am learning electrical.

Comment: @Yogie The core area, Ae, affects the flux density. If you make Ae larger, then less turns are needed. Be sure the rule of thumb is for square inches. 3.3 x 3.3 inch core area seems large for a 100W transformer. Perhaps it's for square cm. If you want to keep the unloaded transformer current low, then increase the magnetizing inductance.

Comment: I built 3 transformers and the third one seems to be working the best of all, thanks for your help; my next requirement is to make primary core reach right below saturation, if given the liberty to choose the core area or primary leg and number of turns, what core area and number of turns should I choose to make primary core reach right below saturation at 220-230 volts on laminated E I cores? 

Note: as per my research so far current has nothing to do with reaching saturation, but if required I can choose SWG # and load as well to make primary core reach near saturation.

Answer (score 0):

Torodial isolation transformer? that seems like a tough ask.
usaually isolation trandformers are split-bobbin E-I or R cores because insulation is simpler in those configurations.

This is the sort of thing you can buy off the shelf, you just need to find the right shelf.   Digikey has a 240V one for $400+ (probably the wrong shelf)  last time I was buying an isolation transformer I paid scrap prices from a recycler's retail diversion outlet, but that was before the copper shortage.

At 50Hz 2.3 volts per turn is going to need a very large core. - the 1200VA transformers in microwave ovens are about 1 volt per turn,  for 2.3 yours would need to be even larger

on a 100VA 50Hz core you're going to need many more turns

> Also, are there safety measures I need to take in order to keep myself from injuring?

put a 2A slow blow fuse (`T2A`) in series with the transformer

Comment: A standard 200 VA core is about 0.23 V/turn, and is about 4.2" diameter and 2" thick. https://toroid.com/transformer-kits/. Plain cores without windings are available on eBay.

Comment: So 1000 turns on a 200VA core  not something I'd want to do by hand.

Comment: Toroids have wonderful efficiency and size/weight advantages, but that comes at the expense of difficult winding. There are automated winding machines for toroids, but you still have to pass a rather large bundle of wires through the core for every turn. You can get C-cores, which are similar to two halves of a toroid, where windings can be made on bobbins. It might be possible to saw a toroid in half, wind each half, and reconnect the cut ends, but it introduces an air gap and unwanted inductance, and it's hard to get a reliable mechanical joint.